# What are Visual Studio "Local Git Repositories"?

Tags: git, visual-studio

In Visual Studio, in Team Explorer's "Manage Connections" panel I can see remote TFS servers, and an other part, called 'Local Git Repositories'.

However, if I run `git --version` in a cmd window, it looks like git is not installed on my machine.

Hence the question: What are those 'Local Git Repositories'?

Answer (score 0):

Local Git repositories are those repositories that exist on your local drive but that are not connected to a remote *TFS* repository.

The way version control historically worked in Visual Studio is that everything went through TFS, since the TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) was the way to do it from within Visual Studio. When they added support for Git, they had to accommodate that Git is not tied to TFS: It’s perfectly fine that people have a repository somewhere on their local drive that may or may not be connected to any kind of remote repository. So Visual Studio needed a way to work with those.

That’s what the “local Git repositories” are: Repositories you have, that Visual Studio does not have a special treatment for (like work item integration etc.).

Note that Visual Studio will *still* work with those repositories using their internal Git client. So you are not required to install Git yourself to use it from Visual Studio; and actually, if you want to use Git from the command line, you will have to install it yourself.

Comment: "if you want to use Git from the command line, you will have to install it yourself" - starting from VS 2017 it ships at least `git.exe` bundled somewhere in its subdirectories and technically you can run it without installing anything more.

Comment: Yeah, VS is using Git for Windows internally, but you probably shouldn’t use the shipped version for you normal Git work. The experience will be rather limited and the version is also not guaranteed to be up to date.